# Exporting Data that exceeded limit

Tags: sharepoint-online

My SharePoint list has exceeded it 5,000 entries. I was trying to export it to Excel, but it won't allow me to open it. Is there a way to either delete an entry to open it or a way to bypass just to be able to access the data in excel?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Export a large list to an Excel will let you work with large list without blocking.

Refer to: [manage large lists/libraries in SPO](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59)

How and where did you open the exported file .iqy file?

Which version of Excel are you using?

When you click Export to Excel to export a SharePoint list on a **Mac**, it doesn't open the file in Excel for Mac and instead downloads the query.iqy file. This is working as expected as the internet query connection is not supported by Excel for Mac.

If you have Excel for Windows, you can save the file as XLSX and then open it in Excel for Mac. You'll be able to see the data but you won't be able to refresh the data connection.

Learn more about [Can't export a SharePoint list to Excel for Mac](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/can-t-export-a-sharepoint-list-to-excel-for-mac-641b0eab-2b7d-490e-9f42-c216b053edb9)

Comment: The version of Excel being used is 2016. When I tried to save the file as an xlsx, it did not allow me to open it. It instead says for me to check if the file is corrupt.

Comment: Make sure your using Windows, not Mac. Check the version of your Excel 2016? Check if the data source location is greater than 528 characters. If the location URL is long, try to update your Excel. Refer to: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/excel-2016-crashes-when-opening-iqy-file-with-long-url-1094922a-ce1b-43e0-aeee-cd188fdbbcb7 In addition, you can try another list, see if you can open the exported file.

Comment: Thanks for the Input. I'm running Windows 7 Professional, but my excel 2016 is updated to the newest version. I can open previous iqy files from other SharePoint pages that has exceeded the limit.

Comment: Do you mean the issue only occurs to the specific .iqy file? Have you tried to open it in another machine?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I was able to open it on another machine.

Comment: try to repair office in the non-working machine